# How does Leetcode create and use objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance

I'm trying to solve a Leetcode question and learn about Javascript objects. This is the question.

```
/**
 * Initialize your data structure here.
 */
var MyHashSet = function() {

};

/** 
 * @param {number} key
 * @return {void}
 */
MyHashSet.prototype.add = function(key) {

};

/** 
 * @param {number} key
 * @return {void}
 */
MyHashSet.prototype.remove = function(key) {

};

/**
 * Returns true if this set contains the specified element 
 * @param {number} key
 * @return {boolean}
 */
MyHashSet.prototype.contains = function(key) {

};

/** 
 * Your MyHashSet object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = Object.create(MyHashSet).createNew()
 * obj.add(key)
 * obj.remove(key)
 * var param_3 = obj.contains(key)
 */
```

I'm confused about the line:

```
var obj = Object.create(MyHashSet).createNew()
```

Shouldn't it be Object.create(MyHashSet.prototype) ?

Also where is createNew() coming from?

I'm guessing Leetcode is doing some magic behind the scenes that I don't understand.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: As far as I know, there is not `createNew` method in JS. Maybe what they mean is that you should create it?

Comment: I looked at some accepted answers and none of them were creating anything called  createNew @quirimmo

Comment: That line makes no sense at all. You shouldn't call `Object.create` on functions, and there is no `createNew` method inherited on such objects. You should just create `new MyHashSet()`. Maybe they defined `Function.prototype.createNew = function() { const fn = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); return new fn(); };`, but really we don't know.

Comment: I've experienced more than a couple Leetcode JS translations misbehaving during competitions. I'd take this likely mistaken comment with a grain of salt.